# A random walk variant

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, random-walk

There are $n$ lights. Initially, all of them are off. Every second, a **random** light will be switched (on to off, off to on). When the lights are all off again, the process ends. What is the expected end time of this process?

Let $F(n, k)$ denotes the expected end time of a game with $n$ lights, $m$ of them are initially on. We have:

$$
\begin{cases}
F(n, 0) = 0 \\
F(n, n) = F(n, n-1) + 1 \\
F(n, m) = \frac{m}{n} F(n, m-1) + \frac{n-m}{n} F(n, m + 1) + 1
\end{cases}
$$

Solving this linear system gives $F(n, 1) = 2^n - 1$. Therefore, the answer is $F(n, 1) + 1 = 2^n$.

The result looks surprisingly simple. However, I don't know how it comes out, nor can I prove it. (I just calculated $F(1, 1)$ to $F(30, 1)$ and found out the pattern)

Comment: the local density is divergent